# Multiple function execution with require_once

Tags: php, require-once

I have a MVC and I have a function: *updateVisitor()*

This function is called in *visitors.php*

And *visitors.php* is included once time with require_one

But the function is being executed three times, any idea?
Is there any php debugger to see where are the functions being called from?

I can't code because it's very huge and I resume it very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest adding a call to [debug_print_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_print_backtrace) at the beginning of your function:

```
debug_print_backtrace(0, 3);
```

It will tell you where the function was called from.

If it prints too many lines, you can limit that by passing a parameter:

```
debug_print_backtrace(0, 3); // would print only 3 lines at each call
```

Answer (score 0):

There're at least two well-known debugging extensions (Xdebug and Zend Debugger) but you can track where a given function is being called with some of the builtin functions such as [debug_print_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_print_backtrace).